# Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have an html form that a user will fill out and print.  Once printed, these forms will be faxed or mailed to a government agency, and need to look close enough like the original form published by said agency that a government bureaucrat doesn't spot that this is a reproduction.  The data entered in the form is not saved anywhere or even submitted back to a web server.  All that matters is that our users can easily find these forms on our intranet site and type into the form for printing with their normal keyboard.

On the screen I want to leave the radio button as-is, to enforce and communicate radio button usage (choose only one option).  However, when it prints out I need it to print with the square checkbox style rather than the round radio button style.  I know how to use a media selector to set styles for print only, so that's not the issue.  It's just that I don't know if I can style the radio button like I want at all.

If I can't get this working I'm gonna have to create a checkbox to shadow each radio button, use javascript to keep the checkboxes and radio buttons in sync, and css to show the one I care about in the proper medium.  Obviously if I can just style them it would save a lot of work.

Answer (score 109):

Three years after this question is posted and this is almost within reach.  In fact, it's completely achievable in Firefox 1+, Chrome 1+, Safari 3+ and Opera 15+ using the [<del>CSS3</del>](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#dropped-css3-features) `appearance` property.

The result is radio elements that look like checkboxes:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
```

*jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Zq/*

**Note:** this was eventually dropped from the CSS3 specification due to a lack of support and conformance from vendors. I'd recommend against implementing it unless you only need to support Webkit or Gecko based browsers.

Comment: is there a way to hide this - before clicking on it?

Comment: Still looking like radio buttons on chrome.

Comment: this solution is not working at all :) i'm not bling and I can see radio buttons being rendered instead of checkbox

Comment: This does not work. Please consider answers bellow or https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 28):

This is my solution using only CSS (Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xykPT/).

[image]

```css
div.options > label > input {
 visibility: hidden;
}

div.options > label {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
 padding: 0 0 20px 0;  
 height: 20px;
 width: 150px;
}

div.options > label > img {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px;
 height:30px;
 width:30px;
 background: none;
}

div.options > label > input:checked +img {  
 background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_34.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
 background-size:30px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
 <label title="item1">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" /> 
  Item 1
  <img />
 </label>
 <label title="item2">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
  Item 2
  <img />
 </label>   
 <label title="item3">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />
  Item 3
  <img />
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The most robust and versatile answer IMO

Comment: It is the best answer @William

Answer (score 25):

In CSS3:

```
input[type=radio] {content:url(mycheckbox.png)}
input[type=radio]:checked {content:url(mycheckbox-checked.png)}
```

In reality:

```
<span class=fakecheckbox><input type=radio><img src="checkbox.png" alt=""></span>

@media screen {.fakecheckbox img {display:none}}
@media print {.fakecheckbox input {display:none;}}
```

and you'll need Javascript to keep `<img>` and radios in sync (and ideally insert them there in a first place).

I've used `<img>`, because browsers are usually configured not to print `background-image`. It's better to use image than another control, because image is non-interactive and less likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 9):

Pure Vanilla CSS / HTML solution in 2021. It uses the CSS `appearance: none;` property.

Seems to be compatible with all major browsers at this time:

https://caniuse.com/?search=appearance%3A%20none

```css
input[type="radio"]{
   appearance: none;
   border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   content: none;
   outline: none;
   margin: 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  content: none;
  border: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked::before{
  position: absolute;
  color: green !important;
  content: "\00A0\2713\00A0" !important;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 21px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio">
<input type="radio" name="radio">
```

Answer (score 8):

*Yes it can be done using this css, i've hidden the default radio button and made a custom radio button that looks like a checkbox.
Working Perfect in 2022.*

```css
.css-prp
{
  color: #17CBF2;
  font-family: arial;
}


.con1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.con1 input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.con1 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #17CBF2;
}
```

```html
<label class="con1"><span>Yes</span>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" checked>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="con1"><span>No</span>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: While this works you did not read the task carefully. The user asked not to add a second 
input-type. Further you might want to give a brief overview how this works. Hide the input put field and show the checkmark span using a custom checked state.

Comment: I''ve given second input field to assure that the radio buttons are working fine..and now have put the checked attribute to first input, it's working.

Answer (score 7):

You can hide de default radio appareance and then draw the check with clip-path in the pseudo-element, no javascript needed.

```css
 label{
     display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

input[type=radio] {
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-grid;
    place-content: center; 
  }

input[type=radio]::before {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    background-color: #fff;
    clip-path: polygon(13% 50%, 34% 66%, 81% 2%, 100% 18%, 39% 100%, 0 71%);
}

input[type=radio]:checked::before {
    transform: scale(1);
}
input[type=radio]:checked{
    background-color:   #0075FF;
    border: 2px solid #0075FF;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit"> Apple
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit"> Banana
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit"> Orange
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit"> Avocado
</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

I tweaked user2314737's answer to use [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) for the icon. For those unfamiliar with fa, one significant benefit over img's is the vector based rendering inherent to fonts. I.e. no image jaggies at any zoom level.

### **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xykPT/215/)**

### Result

[image]

```css
div.checkRadioContainer > label > input {
 visibility: hidden;
}

div.checkRadioContainer {
 max-width: 10em;
}
div.checkRadioContainer > label {
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid grey;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.checkRadioContainer > label:hover {
 background-color: AliceBlue;
}

div.checkRadioContainer > label > span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 line-height: 2em;
}

div.checkRadioContainer > label > input + i {
 visibility: hidden;
 color: green;
 margin-left: -0.5em;
 margin-right: 0.2em;
}

div.checkRadioContainer > label > input:checked + i {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkRadioContainer">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
  <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
  <span>Item 1</span>
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
  <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
  <span>Item 2</span>
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
  <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
  <span>Item 3</span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I pick that one, simple and beautiful, But I'm wondering if I can change the color of the selected `span` when one is selected?

Comment: yes, for example this CSS:

div.checkRadioContainer > label > input:checked + i + span {
    background-color: silver;
}

Answer (score 2):

Simple and neat with fontawesome

```
input[type=radio] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    content: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type=radio]:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f00c";
    font-size: 25px;
    color: transparent !important;
    background: #fff;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:before {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**appearance** property doesn't work in all browser. You can do like the following-

```css
input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
label:before{
  content:url(http://strawberrycambodia.com/book/admin/templates/default/images/icons/16x16/checkbox.gif);
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before{
  content:url(http://www.treatment-abroad.ru/img/admin/icons/16x16/checkbox.gif);
}
```

```html
 
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="test1" value="male">
  <label for="test1"> check 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="test2">
  <label for="test2"> check 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="test3">
  <label for="test3"> check 3</label>
```

It works IE 8+ and other browsers

Comment: is there any chance how to style :before and label so when text of label overflows to the next line, it is horizontally aligned with the 1st line of text?

Comment: @Srneczek I added an image before label as checkbox. So, you know the width of the image. If so, add a <span> around the texts of the <label> and set it display: block. Then add the width as margin-left. Also add float:left to the :before pseudo element. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a control look like anything other than a control with CSS.

Your best bet it to make a PRINT button goes to a new page with a graphic in place of the selected radio button, then do a window.print() from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but optimal solution.

```css
.custom-radio[type="radio"]{
   appearance: none;
   border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   content: none;
   outline: none;
   border-radius:100%;
   margin: 0;
   
}

.custom-radio[type="radio"]:checked {
  appearance: none;
  border-radius:100%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  content: none;
  border: none;
}

.custom-radio[type="radio"]:checked::before{
  position: absolute;
  background:#0c1332 ;
  accent-color:blue;
  border-radius:100%;
  color: white !important;
  content: "\00A0\2713\00A0" !important;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
  <p>Please select your favorite Web language:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="html" class="custom-radio" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
  <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" class="custom-radio" value="CSS">
  <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" class="custom-radio" value="JavaScript">
  <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, CSS can do this (UPS, sign error: This styles a checkbox like a radio button):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + *:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.4em;
  /* Make some horizontal space. */
  width: .6em;
  height: .6em;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px .5px #888
  /* An outer circle. */
  ;
  /* No inner circle. */
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* Inner color. */
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + *:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px .5px #888
  /* An outer circle. */
  , inset 0px 0px 0px .14em #ddd;
  /* An inner circle with above inner color.*/
  background-color: #444;
  /* The dot color */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" checked>
  <label for="check1">Fake Checkbox1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2">
  <label for="check2">Fake Checkbox2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="check2" type="radio" name="check" value="radio1" checked>
  <label for="check2">Real Checkbox1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="check2" type="radio" name="check" value="radio2">
  <label for="check2">Real Checkbox2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: s there any chance how to style :before and label so when text of label overflows to the next line, it is horizontally aligned with the 1st line of text?

Answer (score -1):

So I have been lurking on stack for so many years.  This is actually my first time posting on here.

Anyhow, this might seem insane but I came across this post while struggling with the same issue and came up with a dirty solution.  I know there are more elegant ways to perhaps set this as a property value but:

if you look at lines 12880-12883 in tcpdf.php :

```
$fx = ((($w - $this->getAbsFontMeasure($tmpfont['cw'][`110`])) / 2) * $this->k);
$fy = (($w - ((($tmpfont['desc']['Ascent'] - $tmpfont['desc']['Descent']) * $this->FontSizePt / 1000) / $this->k)) * $this->k);
$popt['ap']['n'][$onvalue] = sprintf('q %s BT /F%d %F Tf %F %F Td ('.chr(`110`).') Tj ET Q', $this->TextColor, $tmpfont['i'], $this->FontSizePt, $fx, $fy);
$popt['ap']['n']['Off'] = sprintf('q %s BT /F%d %F Tf %F %F Td ('.chr(`111`).') Tj ET Q', $this->TextColor, $tmpfont['i'], $this->FontSizePt, $fx, $fy);
```

and lines 13135-13138 :

```
$fx = ((($w - $this->getAbsFontMeasure($tmpfont['cw'][`108`])) / 2) * $this->k);
$fy = (($w - ((($tmpfont['desc']['Ascent'] - $tmpfont['desc']['Descent']) * $this->FontSizePt / 1000) / $this->k)) * $this->k);
$popt['ap']['n']['Yes'] = sprintf('q %s BT /F%d %F Tf %F %F Td ('.chr(`108`).') Tj ET Q', $this->TextColor, $tmpfont['i'], $this->FontSizePt, $fx, $fy);
$popt['ap']['n']['Off'] = sprintf('q %s BT /F%d %F Tf %F %F Td ('.chr(`109`).') Tj ET Q', $this->TextColor, $tmpfont['i'], $this->FontSizePt, $fx, $fy);
```

Those widgets are rendered from the zapfdingbats font set... just swap the character codes and voila... checks are radios and/or vice versa.  This also opens up ideas to make a custom font set to use here and add some nice styling to your form elements.

Anyhow, just figured I would offer my two cents ... it worked awesome for me.

Answer (score -1):

It can be also like this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: #d8046e url("../img/check.svg") center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple with bootstrap radio buttons.

You just need to change the input's `--bs-form-check-bg-image` to be the SVG that is used for bootstraps checkbox's. Don't forget to include `!important`. Set the radio button's input to `border-radius: 0 !important` and you're done.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.form-check-input:checked[type="radio"] {
    --bs-form-check-bg-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='m6 10 3 3 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}

.form-check-input {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
          
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <div class="form-check form-checkbox-item">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkBox" value="yes"
             id="checkBox1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkBox1">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-checkbox-item">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkBox" value="no"
             id="checkBox2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkBox1">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Very simple idea using a table and no Javascript.
Am I being too simplistic?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#ageBox {display: none;}
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
#ageButton {display: none;}
</style>

<tr><td>Age:</td>

<td id="ageButton">
<input type="radio" name="userAge" value="18-24">18-24
<input type="radio" name="userAge" value="25-34">25-34

<td id="ageBox">
<input type="checkbox">18-24
<input type="checkbox">25-34

</td></tr>
```

Comment: The box won't mirror the checked state of the radio button.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.  As indicated by Joel, what ties the two together?  How does this solve the problem?