# how to use checkbox list as radio button

Tags: c#

I have checkbox list, values are extacting from DB by button click. the vaues are ALL,Produc1,Product2. by default all is selected if i select Product1 "ALL" checkbox should uncheck.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkProductOption" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="false"  >                      
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

pls share ur ideas

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Use a [`RadioButtonList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx) and [style the radio buttons as checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox).

---

After clarification, this is what I would do:

In javascript, attach to the `click` or `change` event of the checkboxes, and if any of the products are selected, uncheck the `ALL` checkbox.

Of course, since this is client side, you would have to validate on the server side.

Comment: but it product1 and product2 can be checked at a time. if i use radio button how to implement above logic?

Comment: @ram - Make up your mind. Do you want a checkbox list, where any item can be checked, or a radio button list, where only one can be checked?

Comment: it is a combination of Both. i can select more than one product but when i am selecting the products  "ALL" checkbox slection should go.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely there should be a custom logic involved  because as far as I know no check box list has such a behavior.

two ways has came to my mind that I'd like to suggest:

First, you can have an event handler in place that listens to the check box list and if the selected item has changed checks to see if it's the All item or not and if that is it will check all other items (or uncheck them ) This can be done using a javascript or if the control post back its state every time its state has changed then you can have it on code behind.

Second, you can have another single check box next to your check box list that says " or select All " for example and if it's checked it disable the check box list.