# counting the number of checkboxes checked

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id="SomeID">
 <div class="Wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
 </div>

 <div class="Wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="SomeCheckboxClass">
 </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a checkbox, I want to clear all the neighboring checkboxes in the parent Wrapper div. Basically, I only want one SomeCheckboxClass per Wrapper selected at any given time. For now, I wrote this:

```
$('#SomeID').on({

   change: function () {

        if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked') {

        var TheIndex = $(this).index();

        $(this).parent().find('.SomeCheckboxClass').each(function () {

            if ($(this).index() !== TheIndex) {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
      }
   }
}, '.SomeCheckboxClass');
```

Is there an easier way to do it? After spending some time doing it I'm thinking there's got to be an easier way. Note that the HTML is generated at runtime. Let me know if there's easierr/better/faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using checkboxes as radio buttons ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.is(":checked")) {
    $this.siblings().prop("checked", false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No counting necessary:

```
​$(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    this.checked && $(this).siblings().prop("checked", false); 
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/82QcL/2/

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you a count of selected checkboxes, as your question title asks:

```
$("#SomeID .Wrapper input.SomeCheckboxClass:checked").length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9KcH/

However, as [@dunsmoreb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917217/370103) has suggested, you should use a radio button list to get this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to replicate the function of a radio button. A radio button only allows one value to be checked at a time. Here is an example.

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Hello">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Hey">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yo">
```

You can only select one button per group, which is specified in the name.

**Note:** If you want radio buttons that look like checkboxes, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079482/672118) will be of help.

Comment: Because I want to be able to select one only, just like radio buttons, and then deselect it if I want to. With radio buttons, once you've selected one, you can only select another one but can't unselect all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick try:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $(this).parent().find('.SomeCheckboxClass').not(this).attr('checked', false);
}
```

You may need to tweak it a little.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#SomeID').on({
   change: function() {
      if(this.checked){
         $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      }
  }
}, '.SomeCheckboxClass');
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/yLBMU/1/)**

But if you want to uncheck all checkbox then

```
$('#SomeID').on({
   change: function() {
       $('.SomeCheckboxClass:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
}, '.SomeCheckboxClass');
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/yLBMU/)**

Answer (score 1):

I like to separate the selection from the act of checking if the checkbox is checked. Reads better I think:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
$('#SomeID').on({
   change: function () {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(this)              
          .siblings('.SomeCheckboxClass')
          .prop('checked', false);
      }
   }
}, '.SomeCheckboxClass');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/82QcL/3/