# Grails-Gsp How to make checkBox Group to select only one checkbox out of three

Tags: grails, gsp

I have Three checkbox

```
 <g:checkBox name="startAccountingStatus" value="Yes" />
 <g:checkBox name="startAccountingStatus" value="No" />
 <g:checkBox name="startAccountingStatus" value="NA" />
```

i want something like RadioGroup. Here now i can select all the checkBoxes. i dont want that.. 
I can check only one checkBox.

I can do it in jQuery which i dont want to ..

Is there any way of achieving it in Grails Gsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you go with [HTML radio](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html) group, [also present in Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html)?

You can [make radio items look like checkbxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the check be made on the client browser and not checked at server side after submission the only way is via javascript (jquery, prototype or simple javascript it's little important)