# unchecking radio button is buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rmEe/

the goal is to uncheck the radio button when the user clicks it if it is checked and check it if it's not checked

but then it appears that the click event triggers twice, making the checking/unchecking highly buggy....

I tried a combination of the

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

commands but each of them result in different bugs...

how would I accomplish this goal and fix that code accordingly?

Comment: I'm confused.  That is the way a radio button works by default.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: no by default if you click on a checked radio button it will NOT uncheck...I'm trying to make it uncheck if clicked

Comment: Right.  So why not use a checkbox?

Comment: try using a Checkbox instead.. That will be more suitable for your requirement

Comment: I have to use radio button it's requirements (don't ask)...plz just answer for radio button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with everyone else that a check box would be better.

However, that being said, here is something that may work for you.  First off, the checked attribute being on the radio button marks it checked.  So, to remove the check, you have to remove the attribute.  However, when clicking on the radio button, it wants to put the attribute back.

My solution is really more of a hack.  I am adding another attribute and using that as a flag to determine whether to remove or add the checked attribute. HTH

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
  var input = $(this);
  input.click(function(e){
      if(input.attr('cval')==='1'){
          input.attr('cval', '0');
          input.removeAttr('checked');
      }
      else{
          input.attr('cval', '1');
          input.attr('checked', 'checked');
      }
  });
});​
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using a hidden field to track the desired state of the radio button. Never thought of just setting an attribute instead. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just style the checkboxes to look like radio buttons.  That way you get the best of both.  You are using checkboxes as they were intended and your boss still won't have a clue ;)

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

There are lot's of examples out there if you start searching for this concept. You will want to do the opposite here but the example is the same.

[Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You need a checkbox - that's what they're for. Messing around with a user's expectation of how standard controls behave is a bad idea.

Comment: I know I know, but I Have to use a radio button (not my decision)...plz just answer for radio button....plus that's not actually true, using checkbox implies that user can check multiple checkboxes, whereas using radio button only allow them to check once so there is indeed a difference...anyways, can't use checkbox so plz answer for radio button

Comment: That's a circular argument if I've ever heard one.