# allow only one checkbox to be checked - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview where i have added checkboxes programmatically.
i do as following when creating checkboxes inside a foreach loop, so that they trigger an event when checked,

```
            cbGV = new CheckBox();
            cbGV.ID = "cbGV";
            cbGV.AutoPostBack = true;
            cbGV.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.cbGV_CheckedChanged);
```

So basically when i want the event to be triggered, i have the following below,

```
    protected void cbGV_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //gets the current checked checkbox.
        CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //this code is for finding the checkboxes in the gridview.

            CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbGV"));

            //so basically, right here i'm confused on how i should compare the if/else logic, how i should compare and disable every other checkbox if the current checkbox is checked. Any ideas gues?

        }
```

thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Well, in first place please tell why not use radio-button instead of check-boxes? Still if you insist, then you can achieve the same using jquery/javascript.

Comment: @Daredev - I don't know if that's the reason here, but there is a difference: radiobuttons can't be unchecked (once one is checked), checkboxes can.

Comment: the client has requested checkboxes rather then radio buttons.

Comment: @user1670729: OK... No problem. So, is JavaScript/jQuery an option we can consider? It can be done seamlessly with jQuery. I can provide my inputs for the same if you wish.

Comment: @user1670729: Or why not fool the user by making radio-button look as check-box? If interested, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Zq/; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox;

Answer (score 3):

First, you should only uncheck the other `CheckBoxes`(if that is what you want) when this `CheckBox` is checked and not when it was unchecked.

Second, you can use `==` operator to compare this checkbox with the others:

```
CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
if(activeCheckBox.Checked)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbGV"));
        checkBox.Checked = checkBox == activeCheckBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem here, it only works when i'm going through the checkboxes upward, not downwards. this might be due to the nature of the foreach loop?

Comment: Where did you create the Checkboxes dynamcially? The perfect place is  in `RowCreated` and not in a loop. Can i ask why you don't add them declaratively in a TemplateField on the aspx markup instead?

Comment: btw, could you explaine the following line you wrote,
        checkBox.Checked = checkBox == activeCheckBox;

Comment: That line unchecks all other checkboxes because for only the current checkbox `checkBox == activeCheckBox` is `true`(== is a reference comparison). So for all other CheckBoxes `false` is returned which is assigned to the `checkBox.Checked` property.

Comment: well, i have created the checkboxed under page load, when after binding the gridview. not inside itemtemplate

Comment: You must recreate dynamical control on every postback(with the same ID) in `page_load` at the latest. Otherwise events aren't triggered correctly and viewstate cannot be loaded. I would strongly recommend to add them in a `TemplateField`. As mentioned above, the only other place to add dynamical controls to a GridView is `RowCreated`. It's being triggered on every postback(even if the GridView is not databound), early enough in the page's lifecycle and it's trigered for every row.

Comment: i would really want to avoid using itemtemplates, since i would have to edit allot of code

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it, but here is one way to do it:

```
protected void cbGV_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //gets the current checked checkbox.
        CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
        BOOL flag = false;
        CheckBox selectedCheckBox;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //this code is for finding the checkboxes in the gridview.

            CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbGV"));

            if (checkBox.Checked==true && flag==false)
                 {
                    flag = true;
                    selectedCheckBox = checkBox;
                 }
             else
                 {
                     if (checkBox != selectedCheckBox)
                          {
                          checkBox.Enabled = false;
                          checkBox.Checked = false;
                          }
                 }
            //so basically, right here i'm confused on how i should compare the if/else logic, how i should compare and disable every other checkbox if the current checkbox is checked. Any ideas gues?

        }
```

Comment: hi, this only works when i'm going through the checkboxes upward, not when downwards. this might be due to the nature of the foreach loop. any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;
// to uncheck all check box
foreach (GridViewRow rw in GrdProc.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("ChkCust");
    if (chkBx != activeCheckBox )
    {
       chkBx.Checked = false;
    }
}
```