# Javascript/HTML Checkboxes get checked value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I have several checkboxes, each group with only one selectable component. An example of the checkboxes is below:

```
   <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question1option1" name="question1options" value="correct" onclick="SingleSelect('question1option',this)"> 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question1option2" name="question1options" value="wrong" onclick="SingleSelect('question1option',this)"> 2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question1option3" name="question1options" value="wrong" onclick="SingleSelect('question1option',this)"> 3
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question2option1" name="question2options" value="correct" onclick="SingleSelect('question2option',this)"> 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question2option2" name="question2options" value="wrong" onclick="SingleSelect('question2option',this)"> 2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="question2option3" name="question2options" value="wrong" onclick="SingleSelect('question2option',this)"> 3
    </label>
```

I have a javascript function that pulls out which radio button is selected by passing the radio button group (below), is there an equivalent someone can help me with to get the value of the checked checkbox (only one in each 'group') in a similar way please?

```
function getRadioValue (theRadioGroup)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup).length; i++)
        {
            if (document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].checked)
            {
                return document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS3 supports styling a radio as a checkbox per this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox

Comment: Thanks. The reason I have not used radio buttons is that they look ugly and I cannot seem to find a solution for all browsers and I think your link helps but still does not work in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that same function will work if you correct your calls to `SingleSelect` or your markup; your markup is using names like `question1options` but your calls to `SingleSelect` are using names like `question1option` (without the `s` at the end). Fix that and it works: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/utuvuy/1)

Obviously, though, checkboxes don't automatically de-select other checkboxes with the same name when you click them (that's what `type="radio"` is for). But I assume you know that. :-)

Comment: Thanks, my checkboxes do automatically unselect due to the SingleSelect function. This works great. The reason I have not used radio buttons is that they look ugly and I cannot seem to find a solution for all browsers.

Comment: @user1149620: Yeah, I figured `SingleSelect` probably handled it. :-) Glad this helped!

Comment: Thanks, the calls to SingleSelect are actually ok because its Regex'd but thanks again.