# Get checked elements outside of submitted form with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a web page, at the top is a set of radio buttons and a submit button. Here is the code for that:

```
<form action="/batch" method="POST">
    With checked selection you may: 
    <input type="radio" name="bulk" value="broadcast">Broadcast</input>
    <input type="radio" name="bulk" value="unbroadcast">Unbroadcast</input>
    <input type="radio" name="bulk" value="delete">Delete</input>
    <input type="submit" value="Run batch on checked items" />
</form>
```

Below that i have a table consisting of a bunch of rows with checkboxes at the beginning. Code for that is:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ md5_name }}" class="box"/></td>
```

Is there a way to have the form submit a list of what the checkboxes are and whether they're checked regardless of the fact that the checkboxes are not within the form? Perhaps naming it the same or shared class?

While searching around before posting i found the following snippet from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858200/javascript-html-checkboxes-get-checked-value) which looked promising, but i don't know how running it alongside my POST method would work, or how i would include the result in my POST method.

```
function getRadioValue (theRadioGroup)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup).length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].checked)
        {
            return document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, in the HTML 5 doctype, simply associate those form-elements with a specific form, using the `form` attribute:

```
<td><input form="formElementID" type="checkbox" name="{{ md5_name }}" class="box"/></td>
```

This attribute:

> Indicates the form that is the owner of the element<sup>1</sup>

References:

1. MDN: [HTML Attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

Bibliography:

- [HTML forms reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#forms).

Comment: Much simpler and easier to implement! I didn't realize you could assign things to forms like that. Thanks a lot! I would upvote if i had enough reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a function to the submit method of the form to retrieve the values of the checkboxes, and add them into hidden fields in the form.

Alternately add the default values of the checkboxes to hidden fields, and bind a change method to the checkboxes to update the hidden field.

Comment: As i'm using bottle and therefore bottle templates, i think the second one is the way to go for me. I hadn't considered it as a possibility, even though i'm using the same technique elsewhere. Thanks!