# Using Font Awesome in a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome in a form I am creating. The form is basically a multiple choice quiz that will have a question followed by possible correct answers with radio buttons.

I want to incorporate Font Awesome instead of the radio buttons in the quiz.
(http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) I want to use the icon-circle and icon-circle-blank from the font awesome collection so when the user clicks on an answer JavaScript will change the icon to "icon-circle" instead of the "icon-circle-blank".

Does anyone have any ideas and or best practices on how do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be done by hiding the options themselves and using labels to display the altered boxes. Here's the HTML I used:

```
<input type="radio" id="opt_yes" checked name="test" value="yes">
<label class="icon-" for="opt_yes"> Yes</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="opt_no" name="test" value="no">
<label class="icon-" for="opt_no"> No</label>
```

...and here's my CSS (note that I used the "icon-" class on my labels to give them the supporting styles common to all Font Awesome icons):

```
[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
[type=radio] + label:before {
    content: "\f10c";
}
[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f111";
}
```

jsFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fTdRS/5/).

(based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)'s solution)