# Array to String Conversion error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter

Well I am Stuck some where here in Array conversion:

My Controller:

```
$username = $this->input->post('FirstName');
$countryval= $this->input->post('country');

var_dump($countryval);
```

My View:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="Name" >
<?php
foreach ($countryDetails as $row )
{
    echo '<input id="country" type="checkbox" name="country[]" class="unique"  value="'.$row->country_id.'">'.$row->country_name.'<br/>';
}
?>
<script>
    $('input.unique').click(function() {
        $('input.unique:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the value from checkbox in an array and I need to pass that value as a string further.
I am not able to convert value from array to string i.e if I `var_dump($countryval)` I get value in array ! Please Help. Thank you

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($contryval);`.

Comment: on selecting 1st check box i get output as--array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } on selecting 2nd checkbox--array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have used "country[]" as the name in input field

Please try this incase you need a single value to be returned (Edit made here coz I put type="checkbox" instead of "radio".. I have corrected it) Trust radios for single values.

```
echo '<input id="country" type="radio" name="country" class="unique"  value="'.$row->country_id.'">'.$row->country_name.'<br/>';
```

hope that helps

You need "country[ ]" as name only if it has multiple values. Eg., For a multiple select

```
<select name="country[]" multiple>
  <option></option> <!-- Your options go here-->
</select>
```

You can use input-checkbox too.. But with your question, I believe you need just a single value to be returned.

**Ok.. Now From Your comments I kind of get what you want. Here is my suggestion**

1) When you are having multiple checkboxes with the same name, the values are sent as an array.

2) If you would need a single value at a time and definitely need a checkbox, [You can make a radio look like a checkbox like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

3) If you really want to proceed with your javascript allowing only one checkbox at a time, you can do this.

```
// Load the 'array' helper
$this->load->helper('array');
// Use the 'element' function to return an element from the array
$countryval = element('0', $this->input->post('country')); //should work
```

Have a try..!!

Comment: even after doing so i am getting the same results!

Comment: is the var_dump giving the same output or a different one..?

Comment: i am getting same output.

Comment: Well.. The question is, if you have a multiple checkbox, with the same name, they should be giving out an array. So tell us whether you need a single value or a multiple values from that form?

Comment: I believe my edit should help you out getting a single country out. tell me if You need something else and if I am wrong.

Comment: I need single output at a time, and by removing country[] , still I am getting the same results.

Comment: And i Cant use radio, I have made unique selection for checkbox by script!

Comment: @user3118574 : I have given an updated answer.. let me know if it works.