# Working With checkboxes in the web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have group of checkboxes and that are compulsory to be applied but the situation is user can  be able to check only one check box at a time. So, for this I have implemented something like this with the help of internet. No doubt it works fine when there are no checkbox checked by default. But suppose, one of the checkbox is checked true when page loads, then this does not works unitl I click on checkbox twice.

Here is what I am using::

So , Assuming I have set of 5 checkboxes, I set same class name for all the checkboxes and then

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="myclass" onclick="Checkme(this.className);"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="myclass" onclick="Checkme(this.className);"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="myclass" onclick="Checkme(this.className);"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="myclass" onclick="Checkme(this.className);"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="myclass" onclick="Checkme(this.className);"/>
```

In View page I have declared::

```
  function Checkme(class_Name) {
                Check_OR_Uncheck(class_Name);
            }
```

In Common js::

```
function Check_OR_Uncheck(class_Name) {
    $("." + class_Name).click(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            $("." + class_Name).each(function () {
                $(this)[0].checked = false;
            });
            $(this)[0].checked = true;
        }
        else {
            $(this)[0].checked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Please Help me to achieve this..

Comment: Fiddle will be nice..!

Comment: Why not using radiobuttons? `<input type="radio" value="val1"`

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code in the document ready event. This will register the click event for "myclass".

```
$(".myclass").click(function () {
  if ($(this)[0].checked) {
    $(".myclass").each(function () {
        $(this)[0].checked = false;
    });
    $(this)[0].checked = true;
  } else {
    $(this)[0].checked = false;
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HW52N)

Comment: yes. You are right. It works in document.ready but the problem is I have many forms and If I have thousands of checkboxes. For each group if I define a class and for each class If I have got to write the above method, that is not good. That's why I kept in seperate .js file and i tis not working.The function "Check_OR_Uncheck" is in  common js file and the other one is in particular  page. But it is working partially.

Comment: Actually, I also need it to be declared in ready event I think to make it work proplerly. Is'nt it? If yes then how it is possible with fewer lines of code assuming I have hundreds of checkboxes in a page and there are many groups of checkboxes.

Comment: You can call 'Check_OR_Uncheck' method inside the document.ready by passing the classname for registering the click events for specific group. But here the problem is, if you want to register for 10 groups, you need to call the method 10 times. So you just modify your Check_OR_Uncheck method like the following:

Comment: function Check_OR_Uncheck() {
    var class_name, i, len;
    for(i=0, len=arguments.length; i<len; i++) {
        class_name = arguments[i];
        $("." + class_Name).click(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            $("." + class_Name).each(function () {
                $(this)[0].checked = false;
            });
            $(this)[0].checked = true;
        }
        else {
            $(this)[0].checked = false;
        }
    });
    }
    
}

Comment: Then you can call Check_OR_Uncheck('class1', 'class2', 'class3'); This will take all the classes and attach the onclick event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use document ready handler and call method:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Br32A/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        Checkme(this.className);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.myclass').click(function(){

        var s=$(this).prop('checked');
        if(s==true)
        {
             $('.myclass').prop('checked',false)
              $(this).prop('checked',true)
        }

    });
});
```

Or

You simply can use

```
if(s==true)
        { 
            $(this).siblings().prop('checked',false);
        }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Br32A/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
   $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing a group of check boxes that ***behave like*** a group of radio buttons, I suggest implementing a group of radio buttons that ***look like*** a group of check boxes:

```
input[type=radio] {content:url(mycheckbox.png)}
input[type=radio]:checked {content:url(mycheckbox-checked.png)}
```

This approach simplifies your implementation; you have two one-line CSS rules instead of a JS event handler function, event binding (on both document ready and the HTML element itself), not to mention a possible dependency on jQuery (if you choose to use it).

The catch to this approach is that it requires CSS3 support. For more info, check out this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/279510/2503516