# radio button space and check

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code and have three problems with it. the first one is that I would like to have space between 4, 8 , 16, and 24 when viewed. the 2nd issue is that I would like the radio button to get checked when selected.The last one is that I would like it be initially checked on 8 hrs as default. Thanks.

```
h4
    .span3 Site Name: #{@site.site_code}
    span.pull-right Capacity Reserve Left: #{capacity_left}
    .span6 
      | Reserve Hours Required: 
      .input-group
        span.input-group-addon
          form#hours_select method="get"
            input type="radio" name="hours" id="res4" value="4"
            | 4
            input type="radio" name="hours" id="res8" value="8"
            | 8
            input type="radio" name="hours" id="res16" value="16"
            | 16
            input type="radio" name="hours" id="res24" value="24"
            | 24
javascript:
  $('input[name="hours"]').change(function() {
    //window.location = window.location + "?hours=" + $('input[name="res"]').val()
    $('#hours_select').submit()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the radio box labels into a label tag. That helps solving the first two issues:

Issue 1: Style the label tag to add padding-right.

Issue 2: Use the "for" attribute. For example, in HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="hours" id="res24" value="24" /><label for="res24">24</label>
```

By clicking the "24" label, you would now check/uncheck the radio box.

Issue 3: Just add a "checked" attribute to the input (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp). Example:

```
 <input type="radio" name="hours" id="res8" value="8" checked />
```

Comment: on the 3rd item, when I select another number (ie. 24) it will go back on 8, this was not my intention.

Comment: When does it go back to 8? On reload -- yes, it does. On submit -- it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your first two problems are styling problems. in your `CSS`, use `padding` or margins on `input[type=radio]` or `input[name="hours"]` to space out your radios.

I'm not actually sure by what you mean by "get checked," but if you mean that you'd like it to look like a check box rather than a radio button, that's a styling thing you can probably find with a little googling. One stackoverflow answer is here: [Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

to make 8 the default, simply add `checked="checked"` like so:

```
input type="radio" name="hours" id="res8" value="8" checked="checked"
        | 8
```

Comment: I meant "get checked,"

Comment: they're not doing that?

Comment: can you please provide me with an example for the CSS part. Thx