# Checkboxes:One checkbox is checked and the other cannot be checked

Tags: c#, forms

I have no idea what they call this.All i want to do  t when a user checks one checkbox they may not be able to choose another until it has moved out of the loop e.g if statements.I am using c# forms

Comment: Huh?? I don't see what if statements and loops have to do with your checkboxes.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using Radio Buttons?

Comment: for instance if a user has an array of alphabets abcd etc as checkboxes.If he chooses b he may not be able to use the bcd.

Comment: Then you should use Radio buttons and not checkboxes

Comment: @user2315477 - But what do you meany by "not be able to choose another until it has moved out of the loop"

Comment: Agree with @Saverio - you should use radiobuttons. Btw here is two different forms - WinForms and Web Forms

Comment: Someone else posted a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8079482/1720848

Comment: @Savarino Tarracciano  is it virtually impossible to use a checkbox one at a time?

Comment: Of course you __can__ do it with CheckBoxes but from a user's perspective it would be surprising, which means it would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you should only be able to select one option, and not another, then it is best practice to use radio buttons, not check boxes.

Comment: using radio boxes how do go about it

Comment: @user2315477 - You just use a `RadioButton` instead of a `CheckBox`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property of the checklistbox:

```
checkedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One; //only allows 1 selection
```

Comment: In your C# code. You were unspecific if this was a webform or winform. The syntax for this is for a winform.