# how to clear the previous checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing the selected value to the jquery from jquery in passing to the url to the next page, this is how my check box looks like:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input  type="checkbox" value="male" id="gender" name="gender"  /> Male
</label>
<label class="checkbox" style="margin:-25px 0 0 100px">
    <input type="checkbox" value="female"  id="gender" name="gender" /> Female
</label>

<label class="checkbox" style="margin:-20px 0 0 205px">
    <input checked type="checkbox" value="all" id="gender" name="gender"> All
</label>
```

my jquery:

```
var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(gender);
```

My problem is for example :

When I select the gender male it passes to jquery as `'male,'` but my problem is here when I  unchecked the male and check the female then it passes to jquery as `female,male,` it is not passing the value which is selected now it is passing the value with pervious one, can any one guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Why on earth do you `echo` such gargantuan chunk of HTML?

Comment: Actually, why not just use it as plain html? There's 0 reason to use php here.

Comment: no there is an if condition i removed that for here,because that is not making the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hex20zp5/ your code works fine but you have left out some context.

Comment: Why not use a radio button here? As far as I can see there's no need in being male, female and "all of the above" at one time ...

Comment: As @AxelAmthor stated, use a Radio Button. Check boxes are supposed to allow multiple selections by their nature. It's like buying a bicycle and then wheelieing constantly because you really wanted a unicycle.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery change event as follows

```
$('input[name=gender]').on('change',function(){
    var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    alert(gender);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/phcu8nwg/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all: an id must be unique, as soon as there are two elements with same id (like "gender"), results are arbitrary random.

And: use radio button and you're done w/o any JS or jQuery:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input  type="radio" value="male" id="gender_m" name="gender"  /> Male
</label>
<label class="checkbox" style="margin:-25px 0 0 100px">
    <input type="radio" value="female"  id="gender_f" name="gender" /> Female
</label>

<label class="checkbox" style="margin:-20px 0 0 205px">
    <input checked type="radio" value="all" id="gender_a" name="gender"> All
</label>
```

And if you want the radios look like check boxes, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)