# Check only one checkbox (radio buttons behavior) within an *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, checkbox, angular

I have a Quizz module developed in `Angular2`, so merely some questions with proposed answers and you have to check **only one** answer , I know radio buttons can handle the situation but i want it to be checkboxes with a radio button behavior, the issue is that i did a part of the job but since it is more complicated within an `*ngFor` loop , once i check a B-Question answer the A-Question checked answer will be unchecked and so on.
Here is my HTML :

```
<div *ngFor="#qt of listQuestion"><h3 class="uk-accordion-title" >{{qt.wordingQ}}</h3>

           <div class="uk-accordion-content">

    <input type="checkbox" class="cb"  id="0" [(ngModel)]="qt.chp[0]" onchange="cbChange(this)" />

    <label for="0" class="inline-label" > <b>{{qt.lpo[0]}}</b></label><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="cb"   id="1" [(ngModel)]="qt.chp[1]" onchange="cbChange(this)" />

    <label for="1" class="inline-label"><b>{{qt.lpo[1]}}</b></label><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="cb"   id="2" [(ngModel)]="qt.chp[2]" onchange="cbChange(this)"/>

    <label for="2" class="inline-label"> <b>{{qt.lpo[2]}}</b></label><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="cb"  id="3" [(ngModel)]="qt.chp[3]" onchange="cbChange(this)"/>

    <label for="3" class="inline-label"><b>{{qt.lpo[3]}}</b></label>

                               </div></div>
```

And here is the Script making the solo-checking way :

```
<script>
  function cbChange(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
      cbs[i].checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;
  }
</script>
```

As you can see it is an `*ngFor` loop to load a list of questions ; every question has a list of propositions (`lpo[i]`) and the `[(ngModel)]="qt.chp[i]"` is for taking the status of every proposition (checked proposition) , I think i have to refer every `onchange` function to every unique `ngModel` (as it is in indexing) but i do not know how. Any help Please ?
 (Here is a real image of the situation)

[image]

Comment: Look at this: [Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox).

Comment: Looking at the question wording , it seems like you did not get the point , i do not want any styling stuffs , my checkboxes work smoothly as well as radio buttons , the problem is that once i check an answer in the second question , the checked answer in the first question will be unchecked , that behavior should be per question.. got it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, because only one answer should be selected for each question, I suggest you to not use boolean field in answer-level to indicate selection. Rather, you should store the selected answer in question-level. Something like this:

```
class Question {
    wording: string;
    answers: string[];

    selectedAnswer: string;

    selectAnswer(ans: string) {
        this.selectedAnswer = ans;
    }
}
```

In future, you can easily change the selectedAnswer property and selectAnswer function implementation to cater multiple selections if needed.
The question template then needs to be modified a little bit to accommodate the change:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <p>{{question.wording}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let aIndex = index">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="{{aIndex}}" [ngModel]="answer === question.selectedAnswer" (ngModelChange)="question.selectAnswer(answer)" />
    <label for="{{aIndex}}" class="inline-label" > <b>{{answer}}</b></label><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the runnable plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xMTtFp31rU2ZqCtV8JO1?p=preview