# Dropdown with checkbox only select one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in need of help,how can i select only one checkbox?? Some one who can help me? I have been trying all the things with the knowledge i have in javascript and jquery, but I dont know how to do it? So i hope that anyone here can help me to fix this?

Here is my Html:

```
          <dl class="dropdown2">

            <dt>
            <a href="#0">
              <span title="price" class="hida2 "><img src="assets/images/search/money-1.svg" alt="" style="width:20px; height:20px; margin-right:10px;">Maks. husleje</span>
              <p class="multiSel"></p>
            </a>
            </dt>

            <dd>
                <div class="mutliSelect2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                          <input id="3500" type="checkbox" value="3500" />
                          <label for="3500">3500</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="4500" type="checkbox" value="4500" />
                            <label for="4500">4500</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="5500" type="checkbox" value="5500" />
                            <label for="5500">5500</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="6000" type="checkbox" value="6000" />
                            <label for="6000">6000</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="6500" type="checkbox" value="6500" />
                            <label for="6500">6500</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="7000" type="checkbox" value="7000" />
                            <label for="7000">7000</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="7500" type="checkbox" value="7500" />
                            <label for="7500">7500</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
  $(".dropdown2 dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown2 dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown2 dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown2 dd ul").hide();
  });
  function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown2")) $(".dropdown2 dd   ul").hide();

  });

  $('.mutliSelect2 input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title =  $(this).closest('.mutliSelect1').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
  title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
  $('.multiSel').append(html);
  $(".hida2").hide();
  } else{
  $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();

  var ret = $(".hida2");

  }
  if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0){
  $(ret).show();
  }
  });
```

Comment: `select one checkbox` what do you mean? select for what?

Comment: Why you are not using radio instead of checkbox?

Comment: I dont use radio buttons because i dont like them. It won't work with the design on the page.

Comment: @MoshFeu i mean that i only want that they can select one (only can check one checkbox instead of all)

Comment: You want the semantics and behaviour of a radio button. You don't want the visual style that radio buttons usually have. Perhaps you would be interested in [Can you style an HTML radio button to look like a checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use radio buttons for this purpose.

If you still want to use checkbox, then use like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6336/)

Answer (score 1):

i use this when i need to select only one:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) ! If i only want to get the selected number out instead of the title, then how do i do that? If i look on the javascript up there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio buttons instead of checkboxes:

When a radio button is checked the others unchecked.

Have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know that, but i dont like radio buttons :S

Comment: @StefanLarsen `i dont like` :) It's personally or professionally?