# How do we set "True" or "False" strings to the response of a checkbox for its checked or unchecked state respectively in html?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Hi I'm currently using radio buttons to pass True or False as a string in my project.
I would like to change it to a checkbox that returns the same values, i.e "True" or "False" (based on whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked) so that I'm not forced to change the condition everywhere else in my project.

```
<input type="radio" id="admin"
        name="access" value="True">Access<br>
        <input type="radio" id="donotaccess"
        name="access" value="False" checked="">Do not access<br></input>
```

Any suggestions for the same?

Code for radio button added

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: Checkbox will submit `&xp_table_access=True` if checked, and submit nothing (not even `&xp_table_access=`) if unchecked.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of the checkbox inside a variable `hasAccess`

In the following code - `hasAccess` is equal to `True` or `False` (string)

When you need to verify that the checkbox is checked or not you should use the variable `hasAccess`

```js
var hasAccess;

function verifyCheckbox(elem) {
  hasAccess = elem.checked.toString();
  hasAccess = hasAccess.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + hasAccess.slice(1);
  console.log(hasAccess);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="gquotas-admin-xptable-access" name="xp_table_access" onclick="verifyCheckbox(this)">Access
```

*NOTE*

You should think about using boolean instead of True/False strings

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way of doing it:

```js
$('#isSelected').change(function(){
    var checkboxValue = $(this).is(':checked');
    document.getElementById('returned').innerHTML=checkboxValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isSelected"/>
    <div id = "returned">
    Value Displayed Here
    </div>
```

This is done in jQuery, `is(':checked')` returns true if checkbox is selected, and false if it is not.

Hope this helps.