# how to change the value of a text box according to checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have made 5 checkboxes according to the one which is checked the text in the text box changes. But all the checkboxes can be checked at the same time. I want that only one checkbox to be checked at a time.

```
$(".check").change(function(){
        var text = "";
        $(".check:checked").each(function(){ 
            text += text != "" ? "^" : "";
            if ($(this).prop("checked"))
                text += $(this).val();
        });
        $(".text").val(text);
    });


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text2" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text3" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text4" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text5" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="text" />
```

Comment: If you only want one to be checked at a time why are you using chekboxes and not radio buttons?

Comment: i want check boxes only

Comment: The easiest way will be to use radio button... You try to make complicated something easy to accomplish. By the way is this working ?

Comment: i havent used radio buttons earlier..please guide
yes this is working as stated

Comment: If you insist on them being checkboxes then just change the checkboxes to radios and format the radios so they appear as checkboxes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8079482/1033684

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JS expert so I'm open to suggestion, edit, comment, clarification ...

The idea is to disable other checkboxes and append the selected value to the textbox.

```js
var text = "";
// text += text != "" ? "^" : "";
$('.check').click(function() {
    var $inputs = $('.check');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', true);
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            if (text !== "") {
                text += "^";
            }
            text += $(this).val();
            $(".text").val(text);
        }
    } else {
        $inputs.prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text5" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="text" />
```