# jQuery Validation - with custom Radio Buttons (toggle on/off)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, radio-button

Here's my dilemma:

Client wants form validation on a group of checkboxes, but within that group, there are a group of radio buttons, so that the user can only select ONE of those within that group. The problem is, the client ALSO wants to be able to select AND deselect any of the radio buttons, so I had to find a custom script to allow that functionality.  The problem therein is that this custom functionality needs a dummy radio button that is hidden, but initially selected to flag the checked and data-waschecked attributes, and that is flagging the entire section of checkboxes/radio buttons to be valid, even though the user has not physically checked anything.

Sound confusing? Here's my code:

**HTML: *(the entire form is in a bootstrap form wizard, so I'm not posting the whole thing, only the vital part)***

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="style" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Style*<br/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="panel-group checkbox-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panelStyle" class="panel-title-link collapsed"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Style</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="panelStyle" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleBallad" name="style" value="Ballad"/><label for="styleBallad"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Ballad</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleBluegrass" name="style" value="Bluegrass"/><label for="styleBluegrass"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Bluegrass</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleBlues" name="style" value="Blues"/><label for="styleBlues"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Blues</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleBroadway" name="style" value="Broadway"/><label for="styleBroadway"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Broadway</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleCalypso" name="style" value="Calypso"/><label for="styleCalypso"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Calypso</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleChorale" name="style" value="Chorale"/><label for="styleChorale"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Chorale</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleConga" name="style" value="Conga"/><label for="styleConga"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Conga</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleCumbia" name="style" value="Cumbia"/><label for="styleCumbia"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Cumbia</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleDixieland" name="style" value="Dixieland"/><label for="styleDixieland"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Dixieland</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleFolkTraditional" name="style"/><label for="styleFolkTraditional"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Folk and Traditional</label>
                        <div id="folkTraditionalDetails" class="folkTraditionalDetails">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="folkTraditionalCountry" name="folkTraditionalCountry" placeholder="Country">
                                <label for="folkTraditionalCountry" class="error" style="display:none;"></label>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleGospel" name="style" value="Gospel"/><label for="styleGospel"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Gospel</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleHipHop" name="style" value="Hip-Hop"/><label for="styleHipHop"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Hip-Hop</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleHymn" name="style" value="Hymn"/><label for="styleHymn"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Hymn</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleJazz" name="style" value="Jazz"/><label for="styleJazz"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Jazz</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleJig" name="style" value="Jig"/><label for="styleJig"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Jig</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleKlezmer" name="style" value="Klezmer"/><label for="styleKlezmer"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Klezmer</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleLullaby" name="style" value="Lullaby"/><label for="styleLullaby"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Lullaby</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleMarch" name="style" value="March"/><label for="styleMarch"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>March</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="stylePop" name="style" value="Pop"/><label for="stylePop"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Pop</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleRap" name="style" value="Rap"/><label for="styleRap"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Rap</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleReggae" name="style" value="Reggae"/><label for="styleReggae"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Reggae</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleRock" name="style" value="Rock"/><label for="styleRock"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Rock</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleRockNRoll" name="style" value="Rock and Roll"/><label for="styleRockNRoll"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Rock and Roll</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleSalsa" name="style" value="Salsa"/><label for="styleSalsa"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Salsa</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleSamba" name="style" value="Samba"/><label for="styleSamba"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Samba</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleSpiritual" name="style" value="Spiritual"/><label for="styleSpiritual"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Spiritual</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="styleSwing" name="style" value="Swing"/><label for="styleSwing"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Swing</label>

                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordionStyle" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a id="accordionstyleWesternEra" class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionStyle" href="#styleWesternEra">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Western Art Styles
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="styleWesternEra" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <p class="help-block" style="padding: 0 5px;">You can only choose one of these styles</p>
                                        <div class="checkbox-group">
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleInit" name="style" checked="false" data-waschecked="true" value="" style="display: none;"/>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleMedieval" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Medieval"/><label for="styleMedieval"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Medieval</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleRenaissance" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Renaissance"/><label for="styleRenaissance"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Renaissance</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleBaroque" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Baroque"/><label for="styleBaroque"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Baroque</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleClassical" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Classical"/><label for="styleClassical"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Classical</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleRomantic" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Romantic"/><label for="styleRomantic"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Romantic</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="styleImpressionistic" name="style" value="Western Art Style: Impressionistic"/><label for="styleImpressionistic"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>Impressionistic</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="style20thPre" name="style" value="Western Art Style: 20th Century (pre-1945)"/><label for="style20thPre"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>20th Century (pre-1945)</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="style20thPost" name="style" value="Western Art Style: 20th Century (post-1945)"/><label for="style20thPost"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>20th Century (post-1945)</label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="style21st" name="style" value="Western Art Style: 21st Century"/><label for="style21st"><i class="ion-ios7-checkmark"></i>21st Century</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="style" class="error" style="display:none;"></label>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**Validation JS: *again just a snippet that is valid for this section, since the whole form is massive, and this is the only portion being effected***

```
$("input[name='style']").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'></i> " + "<span>Please choose at least ONE style</span>"
            }
        });
```

**Radio Button Toggle Functionality JS:**

```
$("input:radio[name='style']").click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings("input:radio[name='style']").data('waschecked', false);
    });
```

Even though the styleInit radio button is flagged checked="false" the jQuery validate code is still seeing it as selected, allowing the user to progress.

Comment: As client wants to unselect a radio button so basically he needs functionality similar to  a checkbox. So you can use checkboxes instead of radio buttons in your html and then using css you can show these as a radio buttons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer was as follows:

directly after I declare the addition of the rules for the input[name='style'], I simply added this:

```
$("#styleInit").prop('checked', false);
```

That ensures that when the section is displayed, no matter when, that the checked attribute of the #styleInit radio button is false. This allows the jQuery validate script to carry out as intended

Answer (score 0):

As client wants to unselect a radio button so basically he needs functionality similar to  a checkbox.

So in your html code you can use checkboxes instead of radio buttons and then using css you can show these as a radio buttons.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
-webkit-appearance: radio; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-appearance: radio;    /* Firefox */
-ms-appearance: radio;     /* not currently supported */
```

}

The result is radio elements that look like checkboxes.

Ref. [Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

As you are using same name for all radio buttons (checkboxes now) so you won't be having trouble in applying validation.

Now you use following jquery code to select only one of these checkboxes at a time from the group.

```
   $('input[name="style"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[name="style"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   });
```

I have created a fiddle for the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/paraselixir/MQM8k/1431/