# Functions for disabling checkboxes not working corrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

The functionality is: When 1 of the checkboxes is checked, the other must be disabled. It's working, but after updating the WordPress page and trying to edit the checkbox, i got the following problem:
[image]

First i've checked the Display Excerpt, then updated the page and as you can see, there are 2 boxes which are checked

Checkboxes"

```
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt" onclick="disableContentCheckbox()"><label for="dx_article_excerpt"><?php _e( 'Display Excerpt', 'dxeasypb' ); ?></label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content" onclick="disableExcerptCheckbox()"><label for="dx_article_content"><?php _e( 'Display Content', 'dxeasypb' ); ?></label></div>
```

And here're the functions:

```
function disableContentCheckbox(){
            if (document.getElementById('dx_article_excerpt').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        function disableExcerptCheckbox(){
            if (document.getElementById('dx_article_content').checked) {
                document.getElementById("dx_article_excerpt").disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("dx_article_excerpt").disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Why not use radio buttons for this?

Comment: Can you paste an example ?

Comment: A checkbox can be both checked and disabled.

Comment: Have a look at this answer [Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079482/3993662) on how to style your radio like a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncheck the other checkbox when you disable it.

I commented out `document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = true;` just to show you how it looks when you checked one and click on the other one. Uncomment them in your code.

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_excerpt" onclick="disableContentCheckbox()"><label for="dx_article_excerpt"><?php _e( 'Display Excerpt', 'dxeasypb' ); ?></label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="dx_article_content" onclick="disableExcerptCheckbox()"><label for="dx_article_content"><?php _e( 'Display Content', 'dxeasypb' ); ?></label></div>

<script>
  function disableContentCheckbox() {
    if (document.getElementById('dx_article_excerpt').checked) {
      document.getElementById('dx_article_content').checked = false;
      //document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("dx_article_content").disabled = false;
    }
  }

  function disableExcerptCheckbox() {
    if (document.getElementById('dx_article_content').checked) {
      document.getElementById('dx_article_excerpt').checked = false;
      //document.getElementById("dx_article_excerpt").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("dx_article_excerpt").disabled = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: And here is Jesus ladies and gentlemen. God bless you

Comment: @RumenPanchev glad to help =D

Comment: @RumenPanchev I still don't understand why radio buttons aren't being used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I see it, you have two options.

One would be to change the checked attribute yourself when catching the event.

The second option would be to use radio buttons instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript