# Limit number of checkboxes allowed to be selected in a Datatable in javascript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatable

i have a Data table that has a  column that allows the user to select multiple records in the datatable.

[image]

The problem is i want them to only be able to select 1 record from this datatable.

The ideal solution would be to limit the selects to 1 record and every time they select another record it removes the check from the last record selected. I would like to know how i can achieve this using javascript. Thanks

EDIT -this is my table

```
`$('#email_templates').DataTable({
      pageLength: 25,
      responsive: true,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      autoWidth: false,
      ajax: $('#email_templates').data('source'),
      dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
      buttons: [
      { extend: 'copy'},
      {extend: 'csv'},
      {extend: 'excel', title: 'Email Templates'},
      {extend: 'pdf', title: 'Email Templates'},
      {extend: 'print',
      customize: function (win){
        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

        $(win.document.body).find('table')
        .addClass('compact')
        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
      }
    }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
    {
      orderable: false,
      targets: [0,1]

    },
    {
     'targets': 0,
     'searchable': false,
     'orderable': false,
     'className': 'dt-body-center',
     render: function (data, type, full, meta){
       return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
     }
   }
   ],
   columns: [
   { width: "20%" },
   { width: "40%" },
   { width: "40%" }
   ]
 });

  });`
```

Comment: Can you use radio buttons? You'll get that behavior for free. 
You could even [style them like checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

Comment: Thats exactly what i did. Submit an answer so i can accept it! @Andrew

Comment: Awesome, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using radio buttons instead. You'll get that behavior for free. You could even [style them like checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)