# Need to just display checkbox as radio button , ASP.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am trying to display a checkbox as radio button.

I have tried jsfiddle mentioned in this question but it doesn't work with asp control.

Is there a way to show asp checkbox control as radio button ?

[Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="r" runat="server"  />

input[type="checkbox"] {
          -webkit-appearance: radio;
    -moz-appearance: radio;
    -ms-appearance: radio;     /* not currently supported */
    -o-appearance: radio; 
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a radio button?

Comment: I want checkbox functionality, just need to display it like radio button or anything circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I ended up doing this, works great for me.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  />

                   <AjaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender ID="ToggleButtonExtender1" runat="server"  
                    TargetControlID="CheckBox1"  
                    ImageWidth="16"  
                    ImageHeight="16"  
                    UncheckedImageUrl="~/Images/uncheck.png"  
                    CheckedImageUrl="~/Images/check.png"  
                    CheckedImageAlternateText="Check"  
                    UncheckedImageAlternateText="UnCheck">  
                </AjaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making it round with corners, e.g.:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQbEWw).

Comment: codepen still shows square checkbox, well I used AjaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender. It works fine for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my case it shows a round checkbox. :/