# How to select checkbox name with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable other checkboxes with same name if one of the checkbox is selected. Here is my code:

```
<div id="selectSessionEvening" class="sessionEvening">
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">Evening Session</p>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4:00 PM - 5:00 PM" id="four-five" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="four-five">4:00 PM - 5:00 PM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="5:00 PM - 6:00 PM" id="five-six" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="five-six">5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="6:00 PM - 7:00 PM" id="six-seven" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="six-seven">6:00 PM - 7:00 PM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="7:00 PM - 8:00 PM" id="seven-eight" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="seven-eight">7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$('input[name=sessionTime]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input[name=sessionTime]').attr('disabled',true);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        console.log('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input[name=sessionTime]').attr('disabled', false);
        console.log('not disabled');
    }
});
```

The Code is working fine this way.
Now, What I need to do is I need to pass each checked checkbox in next form so I needed to write element name as **selectTime[]** After doing this My JS is not working now. I have searched for the solution but couldn't get working for me. Do you have any solution for this?

Here is the updated code:

```
<div id="selectSessionEvening" class="sessionEvening">
                      <p style="font-weight:bold;">Evening Session</p>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4:00 PM - 5:00 PM" id="four-five" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime[]">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="four-five">4:00 PM - 5:00 PM</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="5:00 PM - 6:00 PM" id="five-six" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime[]">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="five-six">5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="6:00 PM - 7:00 PM" id="six-seven" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime[]">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="six-seven">6:00 PM - 7:00 PM</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="7:00 PM - 8:00 PM" id="seven-eight" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();" name="sessionTime[]">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="seven-eight">7:00 PM - 8:00 PM</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/humanware/y1c330f8/4/

**UPDATE:**
I tried doing this in JS:

```
$('input[name=sessionTime[]]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input[name=sessionTime[]]').attr('disabled',true);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        console.log('disabled');
    } else {
        $('input[name=sessionTime[]]').attr('disabled', false);
        console.log('not disabled');
    }
});
```

But Got This Error: 
[image]

Comment: _I am trying to disable other checkboxes with same name if one of the checkbox is selected_. Isn't that what radio buttons are for? Also, `$('input[name=sessionTime]')` won't select anything as that's not the name you gave them (in your fiddle). Read up on escaping special characters in selectors. Finally, use `.prop()` with `disabled`, not `.attr()`

Comment: Yes. But This is conditional. Like, I have huge form, if a selectbox has certain value then user should select only one checkbox. Otherwise they can select multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to use brackets in the input names. You could instead reference each input's value from the array of `$('.form-check-input')`

Comment: You're better off restyling radio buttons as checkboxes, rather than trying to achieve mutual exclusivity programmatically. As @j08691 points out, radio buttons have your desired behavior built in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox

Comment: @Tom I need to pass them to PHP so I am passing checked checkboxes via array method.

Comment: @Cybernetic As I've already mentioned, User should select only one checkbox if one of the condition match in my large form. instead they can select multiple checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
User quotes around name when there is special characters in the name.

I have modified your code little here - use this

```
$('input[name="sessionTime[]"]').change(function(){
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked){
        $('input[name="sessionTime[]"]').not(this).prop('disabled',checked);
    } else {
        $('input[name="sessionTime[]"]').prop('disabled', checked);
        console.log('not disabled');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1c330f8/7/)

Comment: I don't think you should use brackets after `sessionTime`

Comment: actually name of input contains brackets and hence it needs to be in quotes otherwise jquery will not undestand it properly

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Your solution is working fine. But is it good to use this method?