# Only checked one input at the time css

Tags: html, css

I want to show content only for checked input and only one input can be checked at a time.
I just want to know how to uncheck previously checked input so that only one input remain checked at a time.
I want this functionality only using css not js.
I know how to do this in js.
This is my code for this.

```
input {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: height 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}

input:checked ~ .content {
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Github repo:
https://github.com/rishipurwar1/faq-accordion-card-main

Comment: Use `radio` instead of `checkbox`

Comment: I tried but it won't work for me

Comment: Could you help me how to use radio button?

Comment: If you use radio it will automatically have your desired behavior

Comment: @Alex After using radio button, I am not able to toggle the accordion item. It uncheck the previously selected input but it doesn't uncheck if I click on checked input to uncheck

Comment: use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
<input type="radio" name="accor" id="ques-five">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/aob9mu2h/1/

Comment: I don't able to toggle checked input to uncheck.

Comment: then use jQuery or plugin

Comment: so, i think I have to js

Comment: use radio button and give the same name all radio buttons.

Comment: and you can change the radio button style as checkbox

Comment: I'll try to implement it

Comment: @George what do you mean by "change the radio button style as checkbox"?

Comment: you can use image to change radio button looks like checkbox

Comment: see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" id="" name="" value="">
```

Comment: If i use radio button then I am not able to toggle checked input.

Comment: Then there may be some id issue. you should check your id name which should be same. hope so that will work for you.

Comment: this is my repo https://github.com/rishipurwar1/faq-accordion-card-main Could you please tell me where I am making mistake?