# Is possible to made radio buttons looks like chekbox, without images?

Tags: html, css

OK, I'm trying to made some radio buttons looks like ckeckboxes, but all the tips I've read tell me that must use the image of a checkbox. I'm not comftable with that, so need to know if there is any way to do it without linking any image to the radio buttons.

```css
input[type=radio].checkbutton {
  margin-top: 2px;
  appearance: checkbox!important;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  color: #717170!important;
  border: 2px #acacac solid!important;
  background-color: #FFF!important;
  font-size: 13px!important;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}

input[type=radio].checkbutton:checked {
  appearance: checkbox;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;
  -o-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="checkbutton" id="2" value="2" name="box">
<input type="radio" class="checkbutton" id="3" value="3" name="box">
<input type="radio" class="checkbutton" id="4" value="4" name="box">
<input type="radio" class="checkbutton" id="5" value="5" name="box">
```

There is any way to style the radio buttons without using unconftable images?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you style an html radio button to look like a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox)

Comment: What are "unconftable images"?

Comment: @phuzi, I think OP means "uncomfortable with using images"

Comment: What you _should_ be “uncomfortable with”, is radio buttons that look like ckeckboxes. People are used to each of those control elements having a distinctive “look”, and associate that look with their inherent functionality. So why _mess_ with that reasonable expecation?

Comment: @sfili_81 All that thread use images, and that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Tnt80 check my answer below if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `:checked` state to apply style to `:before` and `:after` pseudo

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 160px;
  justify-content: space-between
}

/* custom checkbox */

input[type="radio"] {
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before, input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  width: 8px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 2px;
  transform: rotate(44deg);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
  width: 14px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

input[type="radio"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="check" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="check">
  <input type="radio" name="check">
  <input type="radio" name="check">
</div>
```